# java - extensions and external jars on runtione

Tags: java, swing, jar, console

Imagine that I have a java program running and serves requests to other clients.

By parsing strings, I call, or instantiate an object and then use some functions from that.

Like:

```
myjar1.jar { echo(), parse(string)}
myjar2.jar { echo(), parse(string)}
...
myjarN.jar { echo(), parse(string)}
```

How may I add a new jar as a plugin into this list and how can I call it from my super class, app to use this?

I remember something similar with UIManager.setLookandFeel(LAF-String) where you can send an string without being need to import the LAF.jar.

Can someone please show me a simple example of doing something like that? My intention is to update the jar file that I use in my server without restarting it. The server always check for myjar(N+1).jar to use it as the latest updated jar.

This will come very handy when I want to automatically update the client program as well, so client does not need to upgrade or replace any file manually. The superClientApp.exe with check if there is a new jar and if it finds it, then it will use it as the main runnable application.

I hope you understand the concept.
Thank you

Comment: See also [*Dynamic loading of modules in Java*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/415733/230513).

Comment: @trashgod, that is what I was looking for. Thanks